# Formula for covariance of stereo triangulation

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, triangulation, stereo-3d

I am trying to understand the paper *[Determining an initial image pair for fixing the scale of a 3d reconstruction from an image sequence](http://www.ipb.uni-bonn.de/uploads/tx_ikgpublication/beder06.determining.pdf)* by Beder and Steffen. They give a formula (Eq. (8)) for the covariance matrix of a triangulated point after stereo matching. However, when I implemented (rather carefully, I think) their method the matrix in question turned out to be non-symmetric, which is a bit of a problem for a covariance matrix.

Has anyone implemented their method before and has insight on what is going on? Perhaps I am missing something glaringly obvious?

EDIT:
Even without implementing anything, formula (8) feels odd. The matrix $N$ defined there simply cannot by symmetric, because is has $AX$ in one place and $X^{T}$ in the corresponding place when transposed. How can $AX=X$ be true?

Comment: No ofense, but most likely you re implementing it less carefully than you think you are.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Very possible! But please have a glance at my edit.

Comment: But that is **N** (in 9). N is not the covariance, is it?

Comment: @Nope, but the covariance is a principal submatrix of $N$'s inverse. So if $N$ is not symmetric, the covariance can't be either.

Comment: The covarince is the 1:4,1:4 principal submtrix of the inverse indeed (by the paper). If you are creting N correctly, inverting it correctly and getting that submatrix rigth, then the paper may be wrong, but it is very very very uncommon.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Well, I am afraid that's just what happens...

Comment: It could be, but this is a peer-reviewed paper. Experts around the world had giveene this article a green light.

Comment: I am not sure ,  but u can always email the authors,

Answer (score 1):

***A X*** should not be read together.

***N***<sub>(0,0)</sub> =

[image: \left( A^T \left( B \begin{pmatrix} C' & 0\ 0 & C'' \end{pmatrix} B^T \right)^{-1} A \right)]

***N***<sub>(0,1)</sub> = ***X***

***N***<sub>(1,0)</sub> = ***X<sup>T</sup>***

***N***<sub>(1,1)</sub> = 0